# How can I play a video with kivy v2.0.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, kivy

I want to play a video with Kivy 2.0.0 and Python 3.6, but running this code will give me a load error because Kivy's video player won't recognize the file. How can I get Kivy's video player to recognize the file?

```py
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.videoplayer import VideoPlayer
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.video import Video
from kivy.lang.builder import *
from kivy.app import App
import kivy
import os
kivy.require('2.0.0')

# Main page code
class MainPage(Screen):
    """ This is the code for the Main Screen """

    # Initialization
    def __init__(self, **var_args):

        # Constructor for the Main Page class
        super(MainPage, self).__init__(**var_args)

        # Layout
        self.layout = FloatLayout()

        # Video player
        self.filename = '/'

        self.player = VideoPlayer(source=self.filename,state='play',options={'allow_stretch': True})

        self.layout.add_widget(self.player)
    
        # Add the layout to the screen
        self.add_widget(self.layout)

# Main app class
class Video_Viewer(App):
    """ Main build """

    # Main build
    def build(self, **kwargs):

        # Create the screen manager
        self.manager = ScreenManager()
    
        # Add screens to screen manager
        self.manager.add_widget(MainPage(name='Main'))

        # Set the screen to the main sceren
        self.manager.current = 'Main'

        # Return the current screen of the screen manager
        return self.manager

# Run the file
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Video_Viewer().run()
```

This is the error that happens as a result of the code:

```
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading <C:/Users/My Laptop/Downloads/video.mp4>
```

Comment: In your code, I don't see where you have given the path as mentioned in the error log. Still, the reason might be because of your path. As it contains space, it might cause the error so instead of providing a full path, try giving a relative path.

Comment: @AnkitSangwan, That error was provided as an example. The path is set in the `self.filename='/'` block, and the video player's source is derived from that. I've tried using different types of paths, but the same error happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install ffpyplayer

`python -m pip install ffpyplayer`